# Why %26 get decoded when pass as js parameter

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function postBackXTreeRequest(url)
    {  
       alert(url);
    }
</script>

<a class="tab0" target="_self" href="javascript:postBackXTreeRequest('?tvwID=A+%26+B');">test</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tp27tbpe/

Above code will alert `A & B` instead of `A+%26+B` which confused me. Why it get url decoded automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of an `href` attribute is a  URL, so the JavaScript is encoded in a URL. The URL will be decoded before the JavaScript will be executed.

---

Don't put JavaScript in href attributes. Use unobtrusive JavaScript instead.

```
<a class="tab0" target="_self" href="/server/side/fallback">test</a>

<script>
// You'll want a more specific selector that `a` here, but predicting what would suit your HTML is impossible
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    postBackXTreeRequest('?tvwID=A+%26+B');
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use encodeURIComponent in the script:

```
<a class="tab0" target="_self" href="javascript:postBackXTreeRequest('?tvwID=A+'+encodeURIComponent('%26')+'+B');">test</a>
```

Comment: It will still get decoded, it will just get encoded again when the script is executed. I wouldn't take this approach though - you have to do it for every character in the JS that has special meaning in the URL (including those which aren't in string literals). If you are going to shove JavaScript in an href attribute (and you really, really shouldn't), then urlencode the entire script with server side code.